# Cakephp find('list') to get displayField from child model

Tags: cakephp

I have a master model, with a child model. The child model has a foreign key that links to the master model id, following cakephp naming conventions. The child model defines the name/description of the records in the master model.

I'm trying to populate a dropdown listbox in my view with these values (id and name). But the Cakephp find('list') usually gets the information from one model only.

How can I do it so that my find('list') retrieves 2 fields such as :

```
- child.master_id
- child.name
```

or

```
- master.id
- child.name (where child.master_id = master.id).
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is the relation between master and child? master belongsTo child? only that would make it possible. You should not make names up by the way - it would be easier to follow you if you didn't invent names here. It also increases the change of errors sneaking in if you abstract it too much. PS: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

To change the fields for the keys or values of `find('list', $params)` you can hand an array with the key `fields` and the names of the fields you want to use as the second parameter over.

In your example the following code would change the key of the returned array to `child.master_id` and the value to `child.name`:

```
$childs = $this->Child->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Child.master_id', 'Child.name')
));
```

For further information on the find type `'list'` read the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list).

Answer (score 1):

### Just define the fields

For the examples given in the question you need only specify the two fields in the find call:

```
$result = $Child->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('master_id', 'name')
));
```

When find list is passed two fields, they are used as the key and value of the resultant array.

If you do need to return fields from different models, you need to tell cake to make a join. The simplest way is to specify a recursive value of 0 (Assuming the relationship Child belongsTo Master has been setup correctly):

```
$sameResult = $Child->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Master.id', 'Child.name'),
    'recursive' => 0
));
```

Note that in this scenario it is probably necessary to specify the model name in the field list to avoid ambiguous sql being generated.